# Подключение модуля python из другой папки на Linux

Tags: python, linux, redhat

В windows мог подключить модуль из рядом лежащей папки:

```
from libraries import OracleDB as ora
```

Где libraries - название папке. Перенес на redhat и эта же строка стала ругаться, мол, нет такого модуля - libraries. Отличается ли импорт в linux и если да, то как правильно импортировать?

Comment: Версии Python совпадают?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что пишет по этому поводу Д.С. Откидач ("Язык программирования Python"):

> Когда импортируется модуль, например spam, интерпретатор ищет файл с
>   именем ‘spam.py’ в текущем каталоге, затем в каталогах, указанных в
>   переменной окружения PYTHONPATH, затем в зависящих от платформы путях
>   по умолчанию.
>
> Каталоги, в которых осуществляется поиск, хранятся в переменной
>   sys.path. Таким образом, программы на языке Python могут изменять пути
>   поиска модулей во время их выполнения.

Просто запустите Python и выполните две команды:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

и Вам станет всё видно.

> Как же быть чтобы импортировать из рядом лежащей папки?

В этой же книжке, чуть ниже, есть ответ и на этот Ваш вопрос:

> Переменная sys.path содержит список строк с именами каталогов, в
>   которых происходит поиск модулей. Она инициализируется из значения
>   переменной окружения PYTHONPATH и встроенного значения по умолчанию.
>   Вы можете изменить ее значение, используя стандартные операции со
>   списками:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/ufs/guido/lib/python')
```

Ну Вы всё-таки книжку, почитайте!

Comment: Как же быть чтобы импортировать из рядом лежащей папки?

Comment: Например, кто-то предлагает добавить в папку файл __ init __. py, хотя содержимое я не понимаю

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов *Как же быть чтобы импортировать из рядом лежащей папки?* - подправил ответ.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов, `sys.path.append('..')` -- импортирование папки уровнем выше . `sys.path.append('../foo_bar')` и т.п.

Comment: А он там не будет мешаться в этом sys.path? Может его очищать по итогу выполнения скрипта?

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов *Может его очищать по итогу выполнения скрипта?* - это присваивание действует только ВНУТРИ Вашей программы. На поведение других программ оно никак не влияет.